# iOS: Core Data Fetch

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

Entity: `Person`

Attributes: `firstName, lastName, Id`

An example of an array that I get from the server:

```
[Bob,
 Bill,
 John,
 Peter,
 Sam,
 Kyle,
 Jimmy,
 Ryan,
 Willy]
```

The array size of the array being returned will vary.

I want to pass all the objects from the array to some method and get back all the objects from `Core Data` that has a `firstName` matching with all the objects (names) in the array.

I'm thinking using compound predicates to accomplish this.  But I'm not sure what the best practice is to get all the objects back with one `fetch`?  Code example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```m
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.firstName in %@", [NSSet setWithArray:firstNameArray]];
```